# Why can't an Object use a constructor when it is an attribute?

Tags: java, object, constructor, attributes

I have this attribute in a class, that is also an object. For some reason, whenever I try to use a constructor for it, it gives me a Null Pointer Exception.

This is the Class of the Object:

```
    public class Posicion
{
    private int filas;
    private int columnas;

    public void Posicion(int x, int y)
    {
        filas = x;
        columnas = y;
    }
}
```

This is the class that has the object as an attribute:

```
public class Casillas
{
    protected char simbolo;
    protected Posicion coordenadas;

    public void Casillas(char simbolo, Posicion coordenadas) 
    {
        this.simbolo = simbolo;
        this.coordenadas = coordenadas;
    }
}
```

and this is where I get the Null Pointer Exception (first line of the "inicio" method):

```
public class R2D2 extends Casillas
{
    public R2D2 inicio(int x, int y)
    {
        coordenadas.Posicion(x, y);

        R2D2 art = new R2D2();
        art.Casillas('A', coordenadas);

        return art;
    }
}
```

I appreciate all the feedback I can get.

EDIT: This is java language.

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: Java. Using NetBeans.

Comment: You're inventing syntax here. `coordenadas.Posicion(x, y);` isn't Java code unless `Posicion` is a method of `coordenadas` that takes two parameters. You can't call a constructor that way,

Comment: @EJP in his code `Posicion` is actually I method.

Comment: You might want to look into how constructors work. They're not the same as methods: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: Posicion is a constructor. Same reason why the method has the same name as the Class.

Comment: No, it is _not_ a constructor. You might want to recheck how a [constructor looks like](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling `coordenadas.Posicion(x, y);` but `coordenadas` was never initialized, further, `Posicion()` is a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) - in order to invoke it you should use the `new` keyword:

```
public class R2D2 extends Casillas
{
    public R2D2 inicio(int x, int y)
    {
        // instead of this:
        //coordenadas.Posicion(x, y);

        // do:
        coordenadas = new Posicion(x, y);

        R2D2 art = new R2D2();
        art.Casillas('A', coordenadas);

        return art;
    }
}
```

Further, constructors don't declare a return type, so change:

```
public void Casillas(...
```

to:

```
public Casillas(...
```

and:

```
public void Posicion(...
```

to:

```
public Posicion(...
```

And another mistake is:

```
art.Casillas('A', coordenadas);
```

again - this is not how you should call a constructor. I would suggest a fix to this error - but I'm not sure what were you trying to do here.

Comment: `new Posicion(x, y)` that won't compile if OP posted the whole `Posicion` class.

Comment: @Tom your comment is unclear. Why won't it compile ? what will be the compilation error ?

Comment: If OP posted the whole `Posicion` class, then it doesn't contain any defined constructor (therefore, there is only the default one).

Comment: @Tom I think that it was meant to be a constructor, not a method.

Comment: for some reason, if I were to not put a return value, everytime I try to call upon the constructor of that class gives me an error that says: Cannot find symbol. Also, when I extend to another class (through Inheritance), it says: constructor Casillas in class Casillas cannot be applied to given types.

Comment: @crawlingvx Have you read his answer and changed your code as he told you to? You might also want to look at the link that's been provided twice in the comments for your question.

Comment: yes, indeed I changed my code, now I dont get that Null Pointer Exception. But now I have all of the aforementioned errors. I've seen the link you provided, and that's exactly what I did. Again, it caused the aforementioned errors. I'm not trying to be stubborn, I'm not trying to be right. But it's just not working when I don't put a return value in the constructors. It's as if they don't exist

Comment: @crawlingvx see the last few lines of the answer.

Comment: Ohh, ok. I see my error now. Jesus Christ, I've been using constructors wrong for 3+ months now, while my Data Structures teacher in college has been telling me that I was using them right. Thank you everyone, you've been really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Your "Casillas" and "Posicion" constructor returns void, when you write a constructor in Java you don't specify a return type (it returns a pointer to the newly constructed object).

Because your constructors aren't written properly, the compiler doesn't "know" that they are constructors, and makes its own default constructor, which does nothing but allocate some memory, and return a pointer to that memory. So the "coordenadas" variable is never initialized, and retains its default value of "null".